# How do I limit the data returned from Google Places API?

Tags: google-places-api

I am creating an iPhone app, so naturally I want the amount of data uploaded/downloaded to be as minimal as possible.

I am fairly new to the Google Places API, but it seems when making a query if there are up to 20 results on the query, all of them have to be downloaded (up to 20 at a time) and within each of those results, all of the information Google thinks is necessary has to be downloaded too.

Is it possible to limit the max number of returned results as well as what information is returned.

For example, I want my application to query for the top 10 results, and all i need is the name and geometry (i.e. lat/long).

There doesn't seem to be anything that I can see on how to do this so I assume there isn't a way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As answered, it is not possible. However this sounds like a good feature request. Please post it [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).

Comment: I'm not sure if the difference is that substantial. If you perform 1K queries, the difference would be roughly around 20MB. Unless you are on very tight data quota (or a super expensive data plan), it doesn't make much sense to want to save this amount.

Comment: Do you have any idea if this feature is added now? Because I have a similar requirement but couldn't find anything substantial.

Answer (score 1):

You really cant change the format of the Google place API. You will just have to use the fields that you require.

Comment: Thought as much. OK thanks! It's just a shame the iOS 6 maps doesn't have a very good 'places' API!